# Text to Speech and gif Flutter

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech

I am using text to speech plugin and gif in my flutter application. And if the assistant is speaking, I want the gif that appears on the screen to change. When the assistant is finished speaking, I want the previous gif to play. How can I do this?

These are the plugins I use: https://pub.dev/packages/text_to_speech
https://pub.dev/packages/image

Comment: Stackoverflow is the wrong place for this question. The community will help you fix code issues, not give you ideas and write the code for you. Please check the questions guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since text_to_speech 0.2.3 doesn't have a status listener (it doesn't have the ability to detect when speech has started or ended), it's not possible to do what you're trying to do using that package.